# Why does Spring Security respond with 403 forbidden to all my requests?

Tags: java, spring, jwt, boot

I've been struggling with Spring Security for some reason. I've been looking for hours, but I could not find anything. Long story short, all my requests gets answered with a 403 forbidden response. I'm trying to implement JWT based authentication, but it just can't seem to work. Something's up with my Security Configuration, because if I don't mark it as a configuration, and take the enablewebsecurity annotation, then (for example) I can see the basic localhost:8080 login page. Otherwise I can't. Some posts say I should disable CSRF, but that didn't help.

Also, I just can't chain two custom filters before each other. I wanted te JWTGenerator filter to run before my JWTAuthenticationFilter, which would run before the BasicAuthenticationFIlter, but if I give these settings to the configuration, it throws an exception.

I'm grateful for any advice, because I have no idea left, and I'm totally clueless.

## **SpringSecurityConfiguration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    private final SecurityUtil securityUtil;


    public SecurityConfiguration(SecurityUtil securityUtil) {
        this.securityUtil = securityUtil;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .cors(corsCustomizer -> corsCustomizer.configurationSource(new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                    @Override
                    public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                        config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                        config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                        return config;
                    }
                })).csrf().disable()
                .addFilterAfter(new JWTGeneratorFilter(securityUtil), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

## **JWTGeneratorFilter:**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JWTGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final SecurityUtil securityUtil;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (null == authentication) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            CredentialsDTO credentialsDTO = mapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), CredentialsDTO.class);
            User user = securityUtil.findByCredentialsDTO(credentialsDTO);
            SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(ConstantStore.JWT_SECRET.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer("FPE-Weblap").setSubject("JWT")
                    .claim("username", user.getUsername())
                    .claim("authorities", populateAuthorities(user.getRoles()))
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 30000000))
                    .signWith(key).compact();
            response.setHeader(ConstantStore.TOKEN_HEADER, jwt);
            request.setAttribute(ConstantStore.TOKEN_HEADER, jwt);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getRoles()));
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        Set<String> authoritiesSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) {
            authoritiesSet.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(",", authoritiesSet);
    }
}
```

## **JWTAuthenticationFilter:**

```
@Component
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = response.getHeader(ConstantStore.TOKEN_HEADER);
        if (null != jwt) {
            try {
                SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
                        ConstantStore.JWT_SECRET.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();
                String username = String.valueOf(claims.get("username"));
                String authorities = (String) claims.get("authorities");
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null,
                        AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities)); 
//Yes, my roles start with ROLE_
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Token received!");
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

## **UserDetailsImpl:**

```
public class UserDetailsImpl implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public UserDetailsImpl(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        List<Role> roles= user.getRoles();
        for(Role role : roles)
        {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }
```

I was trying to set up Spring Security and jwt, but I just can't seem to find the solution. All my requests get rejected with a 403 response.

Comment: what's your request? what's the  headers? bodys?

Comment: @rick I'm simply trying to send a /login POST request in which I set the username, and the password in the request body. Nothing extraordinary. The only header I'm operating here with is the Authorization. Of course at generating it's null, that's why it gets set later on in the process.